# Is it possible to arrange a foreign key constraint for data in XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, foreign-key-relationship

Some node values inside of XML column reference integer primary keys of known tables. Is it possible to make SQL Server to check this kind of foreign key relationship?

Comment: If you want to enforce this kind of relationship, then it doesn't belong in an XML document.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. I just need to enable some mechanism of SQL Server to check documents against table keys. How does it alter the idea of XML document?

Comment: If you want to enforce key relationships, then you need to shred the XML into tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can!

With the constraint that your document contains a fixed number of such references you can create persisted computed columns for you foreign key as such.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFooRef(@doc XML)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @doc.value(N'(/doc/foo/@id)[1]','int');
END;

CREATE TABLE Foo(id INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE Bar(
    doc XML,
    ref AS (dbo.GetFooRef(doc)) PERSISTED FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Foo(id)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Bar(doc) VALUES ('<doc><foo id="1"/></doc>');
--The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Bar__ref__ ..."
INSERT INTO dbo.Foo(id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Bar(doc) VALUES ('<doc><foo id="1"/></doc>');
```

Comment: Cool! What minimal version of SQL Server supports that?

Comment: I tested this on 2014 so can't really tell. But it seems like the required features are be available in 2005

Comment: I should add that if your xml actually have a fixed number of such references you might want to look into sparse columns and column sets as an option

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, you can't.

You can't directly use an XML `value()` in a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship. For the fun of it I tried creating a computed column that has the result of calling `.value('<some xpath>', 'int')` wrapped in a user-defined function. The trouble with that is you also can't use a computed column in a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship.

Outside of an actual constraint you could attempt to perform validation of incoming `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements in a trigger...but this is already becoming a mess of a solution. As Damien says - this really doesn't belong in an XML document if you want to enforce a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Yes the solution with trigger will work and it is a hard one. What I need is to store semi-structured data and I can't go opposite direction like reference tables with regular foreign keys and build XML with query. There are many referenced tables and structure is rather arbitrary. Probably I have to look for another way of representing semistructured data.

Answer (score 1):

I would post that as a comment but I don't have enough reputation :D. I think you can add a constraint returning the value of a function that would valid whatever you want in your xml. It would not be a Foreign key but it would at least check your integrity.

Comment: Here, have some rep+ so you can comment (: